# Grant read and write without dropCollection in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I need to create a custom rule on mongodb atlas, which has the ability to read and write on collection, but must not be able to drop the collections.

Seeing the guide I saw that I can do the operation by giving only read and write permissions, but the problem is that I have to specify each collection.

Can I apply these read and write only rules without the ability to drop collections on all collections without having to specify which one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i can.

It's necessary set in custom role "all collections" or "blank" for the single operation of write (find,create,update ...) and add the second role (write) from Built-In Role.

With this way I get what I wanted